# How do I read a file, wihout loading it into the memory, like the Delphi TFileStream class in D?

Tags: file, delphi, d

I read somewhere that the std.stdio's File loads the file in the memory, then reads it. I come from Delphi, where there was a TFileStream class, which could be used to read/write files, without loading them in memory. And when writing/reading, I didn't have to worry about the line endings or any special characters, I could provide the number of bytes I want to read/write, plus it could even read/write to/from array of bytes, I'm not sure std.stdio.File has it or not.

Is it possible in D as well? I want to read only a number of bytes from a file, from a position I provide, without loading the whole file into the memory (the file is very big)? If yes, then how? And one more thing, I'll have to read files to array of ubytes(0-255)

P.S: the method should work on Linux, Windows is not my target;

Comment: Do you need the stream abstraction, or are you only interested in file I/O?

Comment: std.stdio doe have the stuff you mentioned there. Don't believe everything you read on the internet, try it to see for yourself first!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No module in the D standard library does what you say you've "*read somewhere*". However, there is a function in the `std.file` module which can be used to read entire file - the [read() function](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_file.html#.read). This function has signature `void[] read(R)(R name, size_t upTo = size_t.max)` and can be used to read *upTo* number of bytes. Naturally, if you omit the upTo parameter it will read the whole file (or fill up your memory!).

As suggested by Richard, use the [File](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#.File) wrapper from the std.stdio module to do arbitrary seek() and read() operation.

If your file is large, it is maybe a good idea to use the [std.mmfile](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_mmfile.html). It is very convenient and allows you to deal with the memory mapped file like it is a slice (array)... [Related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888612/lazily-reading-a-file-in-d)

Comment: std.mmfile is what I was looking for!

Comment: `std.mmfile` is absolutely not analagous to Delphi's file stream. Memory mapped files tend to be used for quite specific specialist applications. Are you really sure that's what you need?

Answer (score 4):

What you want is [File](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#.File) and using the methods seek and rawRead/rawWrite.
It just wraps around the c library, nothing too fancy here.